# Help Understanding huge discrepancy in LDF file growth on AAG between primary and secondary

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I currently have a SQL Server 2014 instance with a very basic AAG setup. There are 2 nodes in the AG. The Log drive on the primary has 90% free space, and the log drive on the secondary has 5% free space. I guess the 2 questions I have are:

1. Shouldn't they always be more or less the same size since they are synchronized?
2. How can I shrink the log size on the secondary without making it the primary first?

Is there a way to accomplish the second one without doing a manual failover, making it the primary then doing all the work? How can i prevent this massive size discrepancy in the future or is this just to be expected? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you have to identify what is filling your log drive. Is it a replicated tlog file or a system tlog file or a tlog coming from a not replicated database?

Comment: its the LDF files from the replicated databases in the AAG. on the primary they are consuming 141GB on the secondary the drive is showing nearly 2TB full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the drive was misreporting space used. The LDF files on the primary totaled 151GB used, after analysis it matched exactly with the secondary. The real issue was the secondary needed chkdsk run on it. once complete, it accurately reflected the used space.